# ALTERAÇÃO DE VALORES EM UM DATFRAME

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ciência-de-dados

Boa tarde. Tenho um DataFrame com o seguinte head():
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observem que na coluna bmi existem valores NaN, mais precisamente, existem 201 linhas.
Quero alterar esse valor baseado na coluna age, então criei estas regras:

```
median1 = base.loc[(base['age'] >= 18) & (base['age'] < 30)].mean().age # media entre 18 a 30 anos

median2 = base.loc[(base['age'] >= 30) & (base['age'] <= 45)].mean().age # media entre 30 a 45 anos

median3 = base.loc[(base['age'] >= 46) & (base['age'] <= 65)].mean().age # media entre 46 a 65 anos

median4 = base.loc[(base['age'] >= 66) & (base['age'] <= 83)].mean().age # media entre 30 a 45 anos
```

Como faço para alterar a coluna bmi seguindo essas condições?
tentei usando loc, usando np.select e por ai vai.
Ex do código:

base.loc[(base['age'] >= 18) & (base['age'] < 30) & (base['bmi'] ==np.nan), 'bmi'] = median1.age
Na documentação diz que posso passar uma condição e o novo valor, mas quando acontece esse tipo de condição mais complexa, simplesmente não vai.

Comment: É isso que vc quer? `base.loc[(base['age'] >= 18) & (base['age'] < 30), "bmi"] = base.loc[(base['age'] >= 18) & (base['age'] < 30)].mean().age`

Comment: Desse jeito, muda todos que estão entre os valores. Gostaria de mudar apenas os que tenham valores faltantes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem uma maneira de fazer o que você quer, mas não é tão direta quanto gostaria:

1. Crie uma função dedicada para implementar o cálculo do bmi de acordo com seu critério.
2. Crie separadamente os valores da coluna *bmi* com a função **para todas as linhas**.
3. Use o método *where()* para substituir os valores *NaN* pelos seus valores calculados.

É um overkill, tem que calcular esse valor substituto para todas as linhas ao invés de somente as necessárias, mas funciona.

```
# função que retorna o índice bmi para um valor de idade
def median(df, age):
    if age >= 18 and age < 30:
        return df.loc[(df.age >= 18) & (df.age < 30)].bmi.mean()
    elif age >= 30 and age < 45:
        return df.loc[(df.age >= 30) & (df.age < 45)].bmi.mean()
    elif age >= 45 and age < 65:
        return df.loc[(df.age >= 45) & (df.age < 65)].bmi.mean()
    elif age >= 65:
        return df.loc[df.age >= 65].bmi.mean()

# lista com o valor bmi para todas as entradas na coluna age
new_bmi = [median(base, age) for age in base.age]

# data frame com a coluna bmi substituída pelos valores novos somente onde tem NaN
base.bmi = base.bmi.where(base.bmi.notna(), new_bmi)
```

Faça o teste aí com seu data frame e avise se tiver resolvido. Abraço.

Comment: É exatamente isto, amigo. Muito obrigado!! Não sabia que poderia fazer assim.